# Non trivial solution of Fredholm integral equation of second kind with constant kernel

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Let us consider the following integral equation$$f(x) + \lambda \int_0^1 {K(s,x)f(s)ds = 0,{\text{ x}} \in {\text{(0}}{\text{,1)}}{\text{.}}} $$
I'm looking of the values of $\lambda$ so that the above equation has only $f=0$ as solution with a constant kernel.
Suppose that $K(s,x)=K$, we obtain
$$f(x) + \lambda K\int_0^1 {f(s)ds = 0,{\text{ x}} \in {\text{(0}}{\text{,1)}}{\text{.}}} $$
By taking the integral over $(0,1)$, we get $$(1 + \lambda K)\int_0^1 {f(s)ds = 0} $$. for all $f$. Now, if $\lambda$ is different of $-1/K$, then $$\int_0^1 {f(s)ds = 0} $$. I don't see how this can be helpful. 
Any suggestions?. Thank you.

Comment: The function has mean value 0 in integral sense over interval 0 to 1. It removes one degree of freedom. This means you have infinite set of solutions. Any function fulfilling the mean value equation $=0$ will do.

Comment: So if $\lambda= - 1/K$ we have only one solution?

Comment: If the other factor is $0$ then it does not matter what $f$ is, since the product will always be $0$ so then all functions $f$ will satisfy it.

Comment: Thanks. I understand, but what I can say about the uniqueness of the trivial solution with respect to $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1):

Your step of taking the integral is too crude, at least initially. When you have
$$
f(x)+\lambda K\int_0^1f(s)\,ds=0,
$$
you can write this as 
$$
f(x)=-\lambda K\int_0^1f(s)\,ds
$$
to conclude that $f$ is constant. If $\lambda=0$, you get $f=0$. If $\lambda\ne0$ and $\lambda\ne-1/K$, your trick of integrating again gives you that $\int_0^1 f=0$, so $f=0$.

When $\lambda=-1/K$ the solution is not unique, as any constant $f$ will be a solution.